# One command to create and change directory

Tags: linux, directory, command, mkdir, cd

I'm searching for just **one** command — nothing with `&&` or `|` — that creates a directory and then immediately changes your current directory to the newly-created directory. (This is a question someone got for his exams of "linux-usage", he made a new command that did that, but that didn't give him the points.) This is on a debian server if that matters.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the exam question was for you to understand why bash functions are necessary.... Making a script won't work (and is a bad answer).

Comment: This isn't a good question for stackoverflow, either like @BasileStarynkevitch said he didn't get the marks because he used a script and not function or he made some other syntactical mistake or it was a mistake with the marking/question itself. The only way you'll find out is to speak to the exams markers/setters.

Comment: Build a script for these two command.

Comment: @user1929959: It *cannot be* a script. See my answer (it should be a *function*)

Answer (score 63):

I believe you are looking for this:

```
mkdir project1 && cd "$_"
```

Comment: Great answer, IMHO. I looked it up and $_ is a "Special variable set to final argument of previous command executed", source: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html

Comment: @BartvanKuik, ...that said, the ABS isn't a particularly good reference to point people to -- it's the W3Schools of bash, frequently using bad practices in its examples and rarely refreshed for outdated content. Consider instead http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/shellvars, or the official manual at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html, or the BashGuide at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Special_Parameters_and_Variables

Answer (score 33):

define a bash **function** for that purpose in your `$HOME/.bashrc` e.g.

```
 function mkdcd () {
     mkdir "$1" && cd "$1"
 }
```

then type `mkdcd foodir` in your interactive shell

<sup>So stricto sensu, what you want to achieve is impossible without a *shell function* containing some `&&` (or at least a `;` ) ... In other words, the purpose of the exercise was to make you understand why functions (or aliases) are useful in a shell....</sup>

PS it should be a function, not a script (if it was a script, the `cd` would affect only the [sub-] shell running the script, not the interactive parent shell); it is impossible to make a single command or executable (not a shell function) which would change the directory of the invoking interactive parent shell (because each process has its own current directory, and you can only change the current directory of your own process, not of the invoking shell process).

PPS. In Posix shells you should remove the `function`keyword, and have the first line be `mkdcd() {`

Comment: Firstly -- `$1` should be `"$1"`. Secondly -- I think that counts as "making a new command".

Comment: no, this is not what i'm looking for (as ruakh said) that's making a new command/function/script or something like that

Comment: It cannot be done like you dream. The `chdir` syscall (`cd` bash builtin) should run in the interactive shell (not in a child process of that shell)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: The answer that you posted does not meet the OP's requirements. If your real answer is "it is impossible to meet these requirements", then you need to include that in the answer you post.

Comment: BTW, if you *are* going to keep the `function` keyword, you should remove the `()` -- that way your code is compatible with ksh (compatibility with code written with ksh extensions is *why* bash has a `function` keyword at all). Right now, it's compatible with neither. See also http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Answer (score 19):

For **oh-my-zsh** users: `take 'directory_name'`
Reference: [Official oh-my-zsh github wiki](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Cheatsheet)

Comment: Wow, thanks for this super trick! I use zsh for years but never heard of that

Answer (score 10):

Putting the following into your .bash_profile (or equivalent) will give you a `mkcd` command that'll do what you need:

```
# mkdir, cd into it
mkcd () {
    mkdir -p "$*"
    cd "$*"
}
```

[This article](http://onethingwell.org/post/586977440/mkcd-improved) explains it in more detail

Comment: `"$*"` is generally the Wrong Thing -- it takes all your arguments together and throws them together with the first character of `$IFS` as a separator. That means that while `mkdir "Directory One" "Directory Two"` will create two directories, `mkcd "Directory One" "Directory Two"` will try to create a single directory named `Directory One Directory Two`.

Comment: Try "$@" instead of "$*", I've heard it works wonders to quote each argument separately, and it will silently omit "" if you have no arguments...

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this is possible but to all people wondering what is the easiest way to do that (that I know of) which doesn't require you to create your own script is:

```
mkdir /myNewDir/
cd !$
```

This way you don't need to write the name of the new directory twice.

`!$` retrieves the last (`$`) argument of the last command (`!`).

(There are more useful shortcuts like that, like `!!`, `!*` or `!startOfACommandInHistory`. Search on the net for more information)

Sadly `mkdir /myNewDir/ && cd !$` doesn't work: it retrieves the last of argument of the previous command, not the last one of the `mkdir` command.

Comment: "mkdir coffeescript && cd !$" worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm not fully understanding the question, but

```
>mkdir temp ; cd temp
```

makes the temp directory and then changes into that directory.

Answer (score 2):

```
mkdir temp ; cd temp ; mv ../temp ../myname
```

You can alias like this:

```
alias mkcd 'mkdir temp ; cd temp ; mv ../temp ../'
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not say if you want to name the directory yourself.

```
cd `mktemp -d`
```

Will create a temp directory and change into it.

Comment: Is there a way to rename the current directory? Prolly.. Cause if so, we could maybe chain it. :D

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you can use some shell script.

First line in shell script will create the directory and second line will change to created directory.